# Hortonworks Sandbox HDP 2.6.5 on Mac with VirtualBox

Tags: hadoop, ambari, hdp, hortonworks-sandbox

I am new to Hortonworks Sandbox HDP 2.6.5. I have it successfully installed on a MacOS Catalina, itself running VirtualBox. All is good - I can access the Ambari dashboard and ssh from my Mac to the Hadoop FS.

However, I am confused about what is where and therefore how to access....

I can ssh using this line:
maria_dev@127.0.0.1 -p 2222

.... and I arrive here:  maria_dev@sandbox-hdp

This looks a lot like the Hadoop file system.

In Ambari, I use the FileView to navigate in the GUI to user/maria_dev

This looks to me like I am navigating the Linux host.

Assuming this is correct(..is it?) , how to I ssh to here (user/maria_dev) from a terminal on my Mac?

Thanks in advance
Simon

Comment: You _are_ SSHing to the linux filesystem. As answered, you cannot "SSH to HDFS"

Answer (score 1):

Ambari fileview is HDFS

You don't see HDFS files from an SSH session without using the `hdfs fs -ls` commands, and this is different from just `ls`/`cd` on its own

FWIW, HDP 2.6 has been deprecated for a few years

> how do I log into the Linux system that is supporting the Hadoop instance

That is what SSH does